# Install package for 18.x on 20.x

Tags: apt

I'd like to install the package `openambit` on my Ubuntu machine. I recently updated to 20.04.1 LTS from 18.04 LTS.
I searched for the package. It is available for 16.x and for 18.x but not for 20.x. (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openambit)

Is there a way to install it on the newest LTS version?

Comment: Qt4 is EOL and was removed from Ubuntu in 2019 (2015 upstream was announced EOL though Debian & Ubuntu supported it until 15-Mar-2019) ; (for more details refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295). The package if maintained should have been ported to Qt5 (introduced 19-Dec-2012) before now.  From your link you can open & you'll see Qt4 requirements...

Answer (score 3):

Two options exist.

#### a. Qt4-based version from 18.04 LTS

It is possible with [special Qt4 PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Erock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4). Install the application by the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo apt-get update

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qjson/libqjson0_0.8.1-3_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openambit/libambit0_0.3-1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openambit/openambit_0.3-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ./libqjson0_0.8.1-3_amd64.deb ./libambit0_0.3-1_amd64.deb ./openambit_0.3-1_amd64.deb
```

and then use it as before.

#### b. Qt5-based version from PPA

There is a [PPA on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Edominik-stadler/+archive/ubuntu/dsta-focal-ppa?field.series_filter=focal) with newest 0.5 version.

To install packages from it use commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dominik-stadler/dsta-focal-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openambit
```